# printing name in multiple for loops and arrays

Tags: c++

I've come across a little problem, how do I print the winning candidate's name?  See the instructions here are, input five names, their number of votes and percentage of votes, whoever has the highest wins.  I don't know if I did my code right, but it works.. well except for the name part.  I've tried everything from a lot of for loops to transfer the array or what.
I'm almost done with the code.

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char candidates[50];
    int votes[5]={0};
    float percent[5]={0};
    int a,b,c,d,e,i;
    int maxx;
    int champ=0;
    char winner[50];

    cout << "Enter the candidates' last names: ";
    cout << endl;
    for(a=1;a<=5;a++)
    {
        cout << a << ". ";
        cin >> candidates;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter their number of votes: " << endl;
    for(b=1;b<=5;b++)
    {
        cout << b << ". ";
        cin >> votes[b];
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "percentage of votes: " << endl;

    for(c=1;c<=5;c++)
    {
        cout << c << ". ";
        percent[c]=votes[c]*0.2;
        printf("%.2f\n", percent[c]);
    }


    cout <<"Candidates\t\tVotes\t\t% of Votes" << endl;
    for(int k=1;k<=5;k++)
    {
         cout << candidates[k] << "\t\t\t" << votes[k] << "\t\t\t";
         printf("%.2f\n", percent[k]);
    }


    maxx=percent[0];

    for(d=1;d<=5;d++)
    {
        if(maxx<percent[d]);
         {
            //what happens here?
         }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it appears you imply a constant total of 500 votes cast because `.2 = 100./500.` Sure you don't want to sum `votes` to get the actual total?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a 2d array of characters or array of string for storing candidate names instead of a 1-d array.

```
char candidates[5][10]; //
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   cin >> candidates[i];
}
```

Then keep a variable to store index for winning candidate

```
int winIndex = 0;
int winPercent = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(percent[i] > winPercent)
    {
       winPercent = percent;
       winIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Finally print name of winning candidate;
cout << candidates[winIndex];

---

In object oriented approach, you may create a class with following information

```
class Candidate
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    float percent;
};
```

Comment: _" you may create a class with following information"_ `struct` would suffice.

Comment: Of course it does. But `struct` is a concept from C, that is why I mentioned `class` to make it in more object way.

Comment: _"But `struct` is a concept from C"_ Wrong. The only difference is that all members of a `struct` will be `public` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string candidates[50];` instead of `char candidates[50];`
then `cin >> candidates[a];`

Comment: _"input five names"_ not 50.